# Where can I find cyberpunk face-cards?

Tags: tools, tool-recommendation

I'm searching for cyberpunk-themed face cards, like [Paizo's](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/accessories/cards/faceCards).

If I just search "face cards" on google I find random, completely-unrelated stuff, and I'm not sure what else I could search for.

Either physical or digital is ok, as long as:

- there are a few samples
- all-human cyberpunk, i.e. no Shadowrun-like or classic-SciFi-like (of course if they are mixed but are ridicusly cheap and they still have a lot of humans, I can just throw away the others)
- all in the same style. Gathering random images is trivial, the whole point of face cards is that they have a consistent style.

Answer (score 4):

**There aren't any cyberpunk face-card decks as game-aid tools I can find...**

I've had the same amount of success you've seen to had and while proving a negative is very difficult I think its safe to say there isn't a commercially available product that would meet your criteria. However....

**Android:Netrunner cards meet all the criteria**

[image]

[Android:Netrunner](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/android-netrunner-the-card-game/) is a [LCG](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/more/living-card-games/) from Fantasy Flight games that has been going on for a few years now and features: 1)Features no non-human races, there are robots, androids, mechs etc. but no dwarfs or aliens or anything of that nature, 2)Has a unified art style across every single card, and 3)You can view images of cards that are already released (there is a 6 month blackout window card database sites use to not interfere with the retail of the physical product) and decide if you like the style or not before you go buy some cards.

You can take a look at cards at databases like [this one](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/) which I've linked to show the core set (aka the starter set) of cards.

**They can also serve as inspiration for NPCs**

Over at [Dreadgazebo](http://dreadgazebo.net/you-got-your-mtg-in-my-dnd/) there is a great article about using Magic:The Gathering cards to create NPCs, magic items, and custom spells. Cards can tell a story through their mechanics, names, and flavor text that you can readily use and Netrunner cards are equally viable for this for a Cyberpunk RPG as MTG cards for D&D.

Comment: +1, but I'll still wait a bit for two reasons: 1. having all the game-related text is not great, 2. likely many cards aren't "a character", but… "stuff". The "this cards depicts a character" cards might not be so many… that being said it's a great game so I could buy it anyway.

Comment: Noticing you now linked some, there are actually many more characters then I remembered, great!

Comment: @Lohoris if you use the online databases you could probably print out just the art, or just cover the card printed info with a sticky note that you or the PCs could write down character notes on.